# How do I model a key/value for which the key is not known in Swagger

Tags: swagger

I have a simple JSON object that can contain key/values for which the exact values are not known upfront. They depend on some server side process. How do I model this in Swagger?

An example of the JSON would be:

```
... 
,message: "invalid length. Must be in between {min} and {max}" 
,attributes: {
  min: 0
  ,max: 6
}
...
```

Another example would be:

```
... 
,message: "You must fill out this field as well because {field} has a value" 
,attributes: {
  field: "age"
}
...
```

Comment: Are they completely unknown is it it from within a constrained long list of options?

Comment: Completely unknown. It's not the best structure I guess...

Comment: It's not the best structure since it doesn't communicate what to do with this information, however, in some cases it is unavoidable. Answer to follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution will only work with Swagger 2.0.

Define the model as described like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "message": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This describes `attributes` as a map of properties, where the value can be anything (string, number, array and even an object).